# How to make SonarQube use JDK8 in Jenkins job using different JDK

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube5.1

I had tried configuring SonarQube in Jenkins using below approach.

Enabling the "Prepare SonarQube Scanner environment" Build Environment option and defining sonar options in 'Maven Goals and Options':
`sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL`

But the problem is my Jenkins job requires JDK7 and the Sonarqube version (5.6.6) configured requires JDK8. I tried multiple ways to define JDK properties in 'Maven Goals and Options' like

`-Dsonar.java.source=1.8,
-Djava.version=1.8,-Dsonar.java.source="path of JDK8"`

Also tried defining Java options in Sonarqube configuration in 'Manage Jenkins'. None of the options is working and SonarQube step is failing with below error:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/SonarQubeMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

NOTE: I do not want to use Sonarqube option in 'PostBuild Actions' as that is deprecated.

Comment: Did you try [pipelines](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204421664-Select-which-Java-JDK-to-use-in-Pipeline) ?

Comment: No,I did not.Can you please guide me on how to proceed with that approach and will that server my purpose?

Comment: the [Jenkins doc](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) seems like a good place to start. Based on that page dedicated to [*Select which Java JDK to use in Pipeline*](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204421664-Select-which-Java-JDK-to-use-in-Pipeline), it seems like a good way to isolate _sonar:sonar_ with a specific JDK.

Comment: can we not define sonar java version in Maven Goals and Options just like how we are defining the Sonar URL as because Pipeline concept seems to be little complex